# Kayaking/canoeing in Korea

Tags: kayaks, canoes, water-sports

Are there any good places to rent kayaks/canoes in Korea?

Last time I rented canoes here, there was a group of 30 people and a guy in a motor boat driving around telling people how to paddle. After about 20 minutes we had to make our way back in.

I'm hoping for something that offers more freedom and quiet, not white water kayaking but a lazy float trip down the river.

Comment: Any particular region?

Comment: I think this would be better suited to http://travel.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: VTC to move to travel, of course that is not one of the options! so I voted to send it to Meta

Comment: @JamesJenkins sending it to meta would definitely be incorrect. If you think it belongs on another site, flag it for moderator attention.